# How to import a module from using url in NODE JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

There's a way to import the following line using node js?

```
<script src="https://assets.pagseguro.com.br/checkout-sdk-js/rc/dist/browser/pagseguro.min.js"></script>
```

I want to use a function from this library.

here's an example:

```
var card = PagSeguro.encryptCard({
  publicKey: "MINHA_CHAVE_PUBLICA",
  holder: "Nome Sobrenome",
  number: "4242424242424242",
  expMonth: "12",
  expYear: "2030",
  securityCode: "123"
});

var encrypted = card.encryptedCard;
```

Comment: the `browser` part in the URL suggests the code is for a browser environment

Comment: have a look here https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Comment: @JaromandaX there's nothing that I can do? I need use those functions in a Flutter App, but the only way I see to do this is implementing an endpoint in the backend to encrypt the data and then returning the encrypted to client-side

Comment: So you don't want to import it. You want to serve the file